# php separate chinese from english characters

Tags: php, string, unicode

How to separate Chinese from English characters in `for` loops?

this is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<?php

function filter_ch($char)
{
return $char;
}

function filter_en($char)
{
return $char;
}

$str='Hello 你怎么样？ How are you?';
$english='';
$chinese='';
for ($i=0;$i<strlen($str);$i++)
{
    $char = substr($str, $i, 1);
    if(preg_match('/\p{Han}+/u', $char))
    {//if chinese
        $chinese.=filter_ch($char);
    }
    else
    {//if english
        $english.=filter_en($char);
    }
}

echo 'chinese: '.$chinese.'<br>';
echo 'english: '.$english.'<br>';

?>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the result:

```
chinese:
english: english: Hello 你怎么样？ How are you?
```

my desired result:

```
chinese: 你怎么样？
english: Hello How are you?
```

Comment: Putting `preg_match()` in a loop is a very bad idea: it's terribly slow. I suggest to use `preg_replace()`

Comment: @HamZa ,  `preg_replace` is for replacing. I think the problem here is because chinese characters take two char space.

Comment: [say what ?](https://eval.in/39753) :)

Comment: @HamZa , I need to iterate on each chinese character. your way is nice except for I cannot run filter_ch function on each chinese character. the problem with my for loop is that it splits chinese character into smaller characters. that is my main problem.

Comment: ok I just warned you that it's terribly slow. If you still insist, try to use `$char = mb_substr($str, $i, 1, 'UTF-8');`

Comment: @HamZa , it worked fine. thaks. How about `strlen($str)` ? should I change it too? my sting would be short so I'm not such worried.

Comment: Take a look at the [multibyte string functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php), you will find [mb_strlen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php)

Comment: found it: `mb_strlen` leave it as answer please so i can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in this line:
`$char = substr($str, $i, 1);`. Since chinese characters don't take 1 byte, it was "corrupting" the characters thus `preg_match` was failing.

The solution to this is by using [multibyte string functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php).
So `$char = substr($str, $i, 1);` will become `$char = mb_substr($str, $i, 1, 'UTF-8');` and `strlen($str)` will become `mb_strlen($str, 'UTF-8')`.

As a side note, `preg_match` in a loop will slow down the script. So I suggest to use `preg_replace()` without a loop:

```
$str = 'Hello 你怎么样？ How are you?';

$english = preg_replace(array('/[\p{Han}？]/u', '/(\s)+/'), array('', '$1'), $str);
$chinese = preg_replace(array('/[^\p{Han}？]/u', '/(\s)+/'), array('', '$1'), $str);

echo $english . "\r\n" . $chinese;
```