# php separate arabic from english characters

Tags: php, string, unicode

in this question : [php separate chinese from english characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17944961/php-separate-chinese-from-english-characters) separate chinese from english, but  not work for arabic characters and not separated, how change that code to work for arabic characters ?

sample code for separate chinese from english characters :

```
$str = 'Hello 你怎么样？ How are you?';

$english = preg_replace(array('/[\p{Han}？]/u', '/(\s)+/'), array('', '$1'), $str);
$chinese = preg_replace(array('/[^\p{Han}？]/u', '/(\s)+/'), array('', '$1'), $str);

echo $english . "\r\n" . $chinese;
```

Comment: Note: Arabic is right to left language, so you may need to but the text in a `p` or `span` with attribute `dir="rtl"` or `dir="auto"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your case you can use like,

```
$arabic = preg_replace(array('/[\x{0600}-\x{06FF}？]/u', '/(\s)+/'), array('', '$1'), $str);
```

Use the following regex to get the arabic and replace it

```
^[\u0621-\u064A\u0660-\u0669 ]+$
```